# How to disable chunking in webpack 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, chunking

I am running react project developed using CRA in localhost in network tab it shows chunk.js files like shown in image

[image]

I want it show original file names like which component file is rendering, so is there any way to configure webpack to disable chunking and show original file names

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.